# OpenCV 3.1: Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. on 1-Stage

Tags: windows, opencv, opencv3.1

it's a common error, but i have searched for an answer and try many suggestions, but nothing works. I use opencv 3.1 on my windows (10) system want to train a system for recognition of playmobil figures.
i have a bunch of 118 positive images of different playmo figures and i have nearly 3000 negative images. All converted into pgm format. Positive images are 64x128, negative images are sized max. 256x256. (I have he original files, too) 
I started training with this parameters:

```
opencv_traincascade.exe -data classifier -vec playmobil.vec -bg negative.txt -numPos 110 -numNeg 1000 -numStages 3 -w 24 -h 48 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5
```

0-Stage works like charm, got this as output:

```
E:\temp\train>..\opencv3\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data classifier -vec playmobil.vec -bg negative.txt -numPos 110 -numNeg 1000 -numStages 3 -w 24 -h 48 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: classifier
vecFileName: playmobil.vec
bgFileName: negative.txt
numPos: 110
numNeg: 1000
numStages: 3
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 1024
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 1024
acceptanceRatioBreakValue : -1
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 24
sampleHeight: 48
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.999
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: BASIC

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   110 : 110
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    1000 : 1
Precalculation time: 20.522
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        0|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 0 hours 1 minutes 32 seconds.
```

But at 1-stage training stops with the message:

```
===== TRAINING 1-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   110 : 110
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
```

I have tried many different parameter. With more or less negative images. Nothing works. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be related to your training parameters.

When training a cascade it might happen that a positive sample is dropped for further processing (as well as negatives). The problem now is that you specified *numPos* to be 110, i.e. all of your positive samples.

When said thing happens and a positive sample can't be used for further processing, the cascade classifier tries to replace the dropped sample by a new one. Since you already fed all your positive samples into the pipeline, it can't replace the dropped ones and exits.

So you should try to re-run the training with a lower value for *numPos*.

For a more detailed explaination, check [this link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4368/traincascade-error-bad-argument-can-not-get-new-positive-sample-the-most-possible-reason-is-insufficient-count-of-samples-in-given-vec-file/#4474)